# Insertar datos desde c# a postgreSql

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, .net

Estoy migrando a `PostgreSQL` en cuestion de la conexion me fue bien pero ahora que estoy tratando de insertar datos me sale un error. Estoy usando procedimiento almacenado de esta manera

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyInsert(_nombre varchar(50))
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO persona(nombre)
    VALUES(_nombre);   
$$;
```

y desde `c#` de esta manera

```
        private void insertar()
        {
            ConexionPsgl c = new ConexionPsgl();
            var Conex = c.Conectar();
            var resultado = false;
            string nombre = textBox1.Text;
            try
            {
                var pgcmd = new NpgsqlCommand("MyInsert", Conex);
                pgcmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                pgcmd.CommandTimeout = 9999999;
                pgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_nombre",nombre);
                pgcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                pgcmd.Dispose();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

            }
        }
```

al ejecutar me sale el mensaje `El argumento especificado está fuera del intervalo de valores válidos. Nombre del parámetro: value`

por favor alguien podria darme una mano con esto

Comment: En que linea sale ese mensaje? por que por lo que mostras, no deberia salir nada de nada ya que el try no hace nada...

Comment: depurando paso a paso sale el mensaje y no inserta nada en la base de datos

Comment: pero hay un try.. se te va por exception no? en ese caso, que trae nombre? tal vez es muy grande?

Comment: no soy experto en postgres, pero tal vez el varchar no esta aceptando el tamaño de lo que pasas?

Comment: como solo es pruebas paso una cadena simple "carlos" asi que no es por el tamaño

Comment: y si le mandas a mano "carlos" funciona? en lugar de traerla desde el textbox?

Comment: sii ya intente de esa manera y sale el mismo error

Comment: Si le pones de esta manera ya probaste? pgcmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@_nombre",nombre);

Comment: sale el mismo error

Comment: ah ok.. entonces el problema es del lado del SP.. que no lo esta recibiendo al parametro...

Answer (score 0):

quizás el problema sea el valor en segundo que estas asignando `pgcmd.CommandTimeout = 9999999;`, si deseas que la ejecución de este procedimiento del lado del servidor se ejecute con tiempo indefinido asígnale cero.

Te dejo este link con la documentación oficial: [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout Property](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout)